# Is it the right time to make homework questions off-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, homework

The sheer amount of homework dumps, especially in the [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) tag, is challenging to say the least. What used to be weekend noise has now effectively spread to the entire week. Can we please finally make homework questions off-topic?

Comment: Most of them are already OT. But that does not prevent them from being posted by users who don't care about rules. The problem is more how to keep those from being posted. Whether the remaining questions are homework or not is not relevant.

Comment: The problem isn't making them off topic, the problem is getting people to take action on them rather than answering them. but people want them reps to put on their resume.

Comment: It is the time of the year, they are working on their end-of-semester assignments.  [c++] is a tag that is particularly heavily affected.  Back to "normal" in about 4 weeks.  Until April.

Comment: @HansPassant Good to hear that. Appreciate the info.

Comment: Suppose we *did* make homework assignments off-topic. What would that change exactly? If as you say "99% of homework assignments" are noise, do you need an entire new rule to handle the reamining 1% that aren't noise, and **would you want to**? Why would you want to target the 1% of **good** homework questions just because they're homework questions?

Comment: @meagar I guess you are right. Appreciate the feedback.

Comment: Many tags are just a waste of time ATM.  SO contributors are swilling away more effort closing the bad questions than the OP's spend on pasting them:(

Comment: The umm. 'economies with the truth': 'I searched the whole internet', (AKA bar was open), and 'I struggled with this for two days', (AKA 2 minutes of copypasta), are actually insulting:(  Why OP's think that skilled and experienced developers would believe such garbage I don't know.

Comment: @Ron I think I once proposed we should keep the [tag:homework] tag as _"honeypot"_ for VLQ  questions ;-)

Comment: C++ is nowhere as bad as C. What really annoys me that most of the bad questions are because the students make the same mistakes that their instructors - even professors - had made. Unfortunately not *all* homework questions are off-topic. Those seeking debugging help, if they contain a [mcve] are still on-topic, and that's a big burden in C. Most of the time they're duplicates of 5 distinct questions, perhaps should be closed as too broad instead.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Whether or not a question is asked as a result of a homework assignment is irrelevant to Stack Overflow, and "homework dumps" are already off topic.

If a question is otherwise on-topic (well-formed, MCVE, not too broad, etc) finding out that it's part of a homework assignment has no relevancy.

Comment: If 99% of homework questions are noise then why not simply solve the problem by making all of them off-topic?

Comment: @Ron Those questions aren't off-topic because they're homework. "Homework" has nothing to do with this. You're treating a correlation like a causation.

Comment: @Ron: Because that applies to a lot of opther questions, too? And how do you find out which are homework and not? The HW questions aceptable here should not even be identifyable as HW.

Comment: @Ron How would making only 1% more questions off-topic help?

Comment: @BilltheLizard How would we even identify that 1%? And again, if we found that an otherwise completely acceptable question was part of a homework assignment, would we close it just because it fell in that 1%?

Comment: The problem is that, whatever you say here, you're not describing the way such questions are treated by the vast majority of answerers. The posts on Meta seem bizarrely out of touch and irrelevant to what is actually happening, and I am inclined to follow established practice rather than some disjointed theory that has no bearing on reality.

Comment: I am sorry for reactivating an old post, but I cannot justify flagging the closing a post for any reason that is not applicable to the post. For the 99% that you(@meagar) claim should be closed, on what reasonable grounds do we have for closing them? (off topic cannot be justified )I am not suggesting a ban on homework questions, but simply a proof of attempt, and wait for a comment suggesting it, before allowing it as a proper reason for closure.

Comment: @Strom I don't really know what you're trying to say, but regarding *"on what reasonable grounds do we have for closing them"*: There are *lots* of reasonable grounds for closing a post. Stack Overflow has a very narrow scope for what is considered on-topic, and a huge number of questions are continually posted which are very obviously outside the scope of this site. I'm not sure what you mean by *"(off topic cannot be justified )"* but I suspect your opinion is at odds with the entire premise of this site.

Comment: @meagar, I am not trying to be at odds with the premise of the site. My post/now comment, was to address the topics not covered by the close flags as they are, a "write the code for me" flag may be appropriate.  I would propose it, but it would be immediately flagged as a duplicate, which is why, I avoid Meta, as much as possible.

Comment: @Strom "Write code for me" is typically addressed by a "too broad" flag.

Comment: @meagar, Even when every condition is satisfied?

Comment: I am not trying to be rude or obstinate, just trying to understand.